# Sheets script to add row(s) based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically what I'm looking to do is replicate rows based on the first cell (or a cell, it can be any cell in the row as needed). IE, if row 1 goes like (4, Blue, 2/15, $5) then the row would be replicated to make 4 rows that look like (?, Blue, 2/15, $5). The contents of the first cell wouldn't be relevant anymore and could look like whatever or be blank.
If this could also be done with a formula that would work as well. Perhaps created on a new sheet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read all of your data and then overwrite it with the new data, right?

```
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
result = [];

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
repeat = data[i][0];//looks at the first column
if (repeat > 0)
   {
    for (var j=0;j<repeat;j++){ result.push(["?",data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3]]);
   }
}

s.getDataRange.clear();
s.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
```

If you want the result somewhere else, skip the second to last line and have the final line point somewhere other than s.